# How to get back TTL-exceeded error messages from UDP packets in C on Linux without root privledges?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, ttl

I want to send out a UDP packet with a short TTL value and get back the TTL-exceeded error message without having root privileges. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Set UDP socket options:

Copied from (http://www.codeforge.com/read/3605/tracepath.c__html)

```
on = IP_PMTUDISC_DO; // sets the Don't-Fragment flag

setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_MTU_DISCOVER, &on, sizeof(on)); // Set or receive the Path MTU Discovery setting for a socket. When enabled, Linux will perform Path MTU Discovery

setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, &on, sizeof(on)); // Enable extended reliable error message passing. When enabled on a datagram socket, all generated errors will be queued in a per-socket error queue.

// When the user receives an error from a socket operation, the errors can be received by calling recvmsg(2) with the MSG_ERRQUEUE flag set.

setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_RECVTTL, &on, sizeof(on)); // When this flag is set, pass a IP_TTL control message with the time to live field of the received packet as a byte. Not supported for SOCK_STREAM sockets.
```

It appears that I can then get the TTL_Exceeded error message from there in the form of a sock_extended_err structure.